# Asynchronous Easy Table scripts in Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

In Azure Portal, I'm modifying the scripts of an Easy Table, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly return a response to a client within a modified script. This is using the node package `azure-mobile-apps`

Just as a simple example, let's say I had a table that I was modifying the 'insert' function on, like so:

```
function getUserHeader(context) {
    return context.req.headers['user-id'];
}


table.insert(function (context) {
  context.item._user_id = getUserHeader(context);
  return context.execute();
});
```

Now this is all fine, works perfectly as expected, item on the table ends up with correct _user_id and everything.

But let's say, for whatever reason, I had to make `getUserHeader` asynchronous and return a promise (maybe I want to verify a token or check something on a related table before executing the context). Here's what the above code might look like async:

```
function getUserHeader(context) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve(context.req.headers['user-id']);
    });
}


table.insert(function (context) {
  getUserHeader(context)
    .then(function(uid) {
        context.item._user_id = uid;
        return context.execute();
    })      
});
```

Now it works on one level: `context.execute` does run, and the record does get created, with the correct _user_id. HOWEVER the http call the client made never gets a response. Normally the http response returns with the item that cot added to the table (in the case of insert), but not here.

What's the proper way to add in asychronous functions to the workflow of the easy table scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `return` keyword when you call a Promise function.

This would work if you change it to:

```
table.insert(function (context) {
    return getUserHeader(context).then(function(uid) {
        context.item._user_id = uid;
        return context.execute();
    })      
});
```

Comment: I will try that when i get home. I did think to try that, I thought I already had, but I'll try again.